# Add Microdata/Schema.org autocompletion suport to PHPStorm

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, schema.org, microdata

Exist way add schema.org autocompletion to PHPStorm ?

For example I want autocompletion for

```
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"
```

Answer (score 11):

yes. For the code like

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
    My name is <span itemprop="name">Smith</span>
    <span itemprop="<ctrl+space here>" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
        <span itemprop="locality">Albuquerque</span>
        <span itemprop="region">NM</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

completion suggests the corresponding properties. But you need to fetch the resource to make it work - hit Alt+Enter on the URL and choose 'Fetch external resource'

Comment: Which link should I add to external resource. I tried add http://schema.org/Person, but nothing changes.

Comment: put cursor on URL in your HTML (http://schema.org/Article is your sample), hit Alt+Enter, choose 'Fetch external resource' from the drop-down

Comment: if I understand I already discussed problem with you here - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/30572 ;)

Comment: Should be added that currently proper schema is `http://schema.org` because `data-vocabulary.org` is deprecated by Google search engines.